# Postgresql Trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a update query,

```
UPDATE tableA SET column1 = $1 WHERE id = $2 AND date < $3
```

and date is null and is not set yet.
I also have trigger which is

```
BEFORE UPDATE OF column1 ON tableA FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION functionA()
```

My question is does the trigger run before the update query even if date is null in WHERE clause?
If not, how can I make the trigger run before the update query even though date is null and set date inside the functionA?

Comment: The trigger fires for each row that is affected by the query. It does not fire if no row is affected. Please explain what you are really trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to set date to now using trigger (maybe using a new function inside trigger) before the update query runs because at first there is no data for date (null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger will not fire when date is null. The condition "date < $3" evaluates to NULL when date is NULL. The "AND" requires both conditions return TRUE, since NULL is not TRUE no rows are affected so as @GMB indicates the trigger does not fire. If your trigger function will be setting the date column then perhaps you want:

```
update tablea 
   set column1 = $1 
 where id = $2 
   and (date < $3 or date is null) ;
```